# Changes to OSGi bundle not active until AEM restarted

Tags: maven, osgi, aem, apache-felix

I have a sling **Servlet** (and various other components) running inside an OSGi bundle inside AEM / Apache Felix.

eg:

```
@SlingServlet(
        label = "XXXX - SSO Post Servlet",
        metatype = true,
        methods = {"POST"},
        name = "XXXX.core.components.SlingPostServlet",
        paths = {"/services/SSOPost"}
)
public class SlingPostServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
  //etc
```

My components work as expected, maven is able to build, bundle and deploy the entire project fine.

My issue is that updates to my components are not activated until I restart the entire AEM instance. I have tried refreshing OSGi packages, restarting the bundle, and as many likely UI actions to achieve this effect as I can think of, but no luck.

Any ideas? I'm hoping its a simple config issue/ button I am not aware of.

Thanks.

Comment: do you see nodes under this path /system/sling/installer/jcr/pauseInstallation when you install the updated package ?

Comment: @SharathMadappa no, there are no nodes at all under that path before or after install.

Comment: after building the updated code, open the configurations for JcrInstaller and save it (the goal is get the activate method of JcrInstaller to fire). Does this have the same effect as restarting the instance w.r.t update of components ?

Comment: How are you deploying your bundle to the instance? Via Maven plugins or manually?
Also do your components have any OSGI properties associated to it? Usually the properties are bound to a specific version of jar and may need to be unbind via configuration manager to actually reflect the changes.

Comment: We beed more information, what version of AEM? Can you replicate this behavior in a new clean project? Can you replicate this in a new clean instance? You have to start a process of elimination to narrow the issue down.

Answer (score 0):

The bundle is started but the event might not be active. It should get activated when the service is actually used. We can use the `@Component(immediate=true)` annotation to activate the component when the bundle gets started

Comment: I really wanted this to be right, but not quite there yet...the (immediate=true) property is not valid for the \@SlingServlet annotation and a class can't be a \@SlingServlet and a \@Component at the same time as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the old jar first, and then deploy the new jar. This works for me most of the times, but not always.